# handcrafted MATLAB desktop shortcut (/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop) broken

Tags: command-line, software-installation, ubuntu-gnome

**In short**: My desktop shortcut for MATLAB fails. It is very likely not a problem with MATLAB but how I made the `.desktop` file. How can I fix that, what did I do wrong? Here's the full story:

I installed MATLAB on Ubuntu 20.04 manually. I installed it in `/opt/` and created a `matlab.sh` as well as a matlab symbolic link inside `/usr/local/bin`.

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 janv. 19 17:18 matlab -> /opt/MATLAB/matlab.sh*
```

**matlab.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

LIGHT_ORANGE_COLOR="\e[38;5;216m"
TURQUOISE_COLOR="\e[38;5;43m"
LIGHT_BLUE_COLOR="\e[38;5;153m"
RED_COLOR="\e[38;5;196m"
NO_COLOR="\e[0m"

echo -e "${TURQUOISE_COLOR}### starting MATLAB ###${NO_COLOR}"
/opt/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/matlab
```

When I type `matlab` in a new terminal, it starts and run properly. Then I decided to create a desktop shortcut with `sudo gedit matlab.desktop` inside `/usr/share/applications` :

**matlab.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Matlab
Comment=Matlab student version
GenericName=Matlab
Exec=matlab
Icon=/opt/MATLAB/matlab_logo.png
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Matlab;MATLAB;Maths;
```

On the desktop application menu, I now have a fancy clickable icon for MATLAB. However, when I click on it, I can see the blue square with MATLAB logo meaning the software is starting properly and then nothing. On `htop` I can see that the process disappears a few seconds after launch.

I'm confused since my `matlab` command works flawlessly...

Any idea how to fix that?